# Why is cache_discovery not rebuilt on cache-rebuild?

Tags: 8, caching

In my local dev environment `drush cr` does not rebuild the `cache_discovery` table.  I have to manually truncate it.  Is it because `expire` is set to `-1` on all rows?  If so, did I mess something up in setting up this site?

I *think* I could add `$settings['cache']['bins']['discovery'] = 'cache.backend.null';` in my local settings file, but then I'd have to truncate it in production when making changes like the one that brought this up.  This doesn't seem right.

Maybe I'm just missing a setting somewhere, but `drush cr`, `rebuild.php`, and restarting apache all leave `cache_discovery` exactly as it was.

Answer (score 1):

If you truncate the table `cache_discovery` and then do a cache-rebuild the table is filled again with data, what would not be, if this was still a cache-clear. In D8 clearing the cache is more like rebuilding the cache, hence the new name. Some tables are still cleared, like the render cache or the twig cache, because these are filled with new data from the result of each request. But the structural data like discovery, router, config and some more are rebuilt, so that the first request after clearing the cache doesn't take too long.

If you set `$settings['cache']['bins']['discovery'] = 'cache.backend.null';`, then you freeze the table content. It is not touched, even not by a cache rebuild, until you remove this setting.

Comment: Thanks.  So what is the proper way to "re-discover" configuration?  For example, adding a form mode to a custom entity.  Is truncating the table the only way short of uninstall/reinstall?

In this case, the table is not being rebuilt, I took note of the created timestamps and they did not change

Comment: Adding a form mode is discovered by a cache-rebuild. No need to re-install the module.

Comment: Maybe I need to rephrase the question to _what would cause a form mode to not be discovered by a cache-rebuild_?  Every row in cache_discovery has `expire` set to `-1` and doing a cache_rebuild *does not* update the records.  The only way I could get the records to update were to truncate the table and then rebuild the cache.

Comment: On second thought, the original question could just be edited to _Why is cache_discovery not rebuilt on cache-rebuild?_

Comment: No, expire is not the problem, this is always -1, because a time-based invalidation would make no sense.

Comment: What could cause this, see the second part of the answer. Probably you should check other dev settings too.

Comment: I think this is a core bug. I have stumbled upon a few instances now of drush deploy (updb, cim, cr) not working until cache_discovery was manually emptied. I guess it could be done with a drush command and added to our deployment scripts.